# JavaScript while loop not working with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I have created horizontal menu. Now i want if total li width is greater than screen width then some li should be display none from last. Below is my code that is not working. This code is working just for last li then it is crushing the browser. And i wish to use this type of code to responsive web page. I don't know whether this type of code is used for responsive or not.  Please help.

```js
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("nav>ul>li");
var availableWidth = document.querySelector("body").offsetWidth;
var liWidth = 0;
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  liWidth = liWidth + arr[i].offsetWidth;
}
while (liWidth > availableWidth) {
  arr[arr.length - 1].style.display = "none";
  arr = document.querySelectorAll("nav>ul>li");
  liWidth = 0;
  i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    liWidth = liWidth + arr[i].offsetWidth;
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul li a {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

ul li:last-child a {
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav id="testi">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Post</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Poems</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">About</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Drop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Without fixing your code, let me point you in a different direction entirely.  Checkout flexbox.  You shouldn't be writing code to check the browser size and adjust your elements.  Flexbox is made for responsive layouts. 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: I know about flexible box. It dose not matter. I have to find out the errors of my js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be your line:
`arr[arr.length - 1].style.display = "none";`

Your hidden elements are still in this array. Thus, your code just keep setting display none on the last element. The simplest fix is to keep an index of which element you need to hide next.

That said, this is all pretty cringey, even if you insist on doing it in Javascript and not CSS. There is no need to re-run the querySelectorAll on each loop. In addition, you can do this with just one loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    liWidth += arr[i].offsetWidth;
    if (liWidth > availableWidth) {
        arr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```